# How do I blit specific indexes of text to the screen in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame
import math

def StoryLine():

    pygame.init()

    width = 1104
    height = 644

    white = 255,255,255
    red = 255,0,0
    color = 255,0,0
    black = 0,0,0
    cyan = 0,255,255

    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('War Games 3')

    Map = pygame.image.load('Map3Cut.png')
    Map = pygame.transform.scale(Map, (1104,644))

    stop = False

    while not stop:

        gameDisplay.blit(Map, (0,0))

        StoryText = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",25)

        StoryFont = StoryText.render('Click ENTER to continue...',5,(red))
        gameDisplay.blit(StoryFont,(50,500))
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                     mainGame()

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        pygame.display.update()
```

Here I have some text that tells the user to click enter to continue. I was wondering how I could blit only one index of the string for example I could blit
StoryFont[1] and that would only blit 'l' to the screen. I did try this and it did not work. Thank you for any help.

Comment: What does Blit mean? Is that somethin :  specific to pygame?

Comment: Blit is the function used to render something on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't edit a pygame render instance. However, you could create a variable that contains a normal string, then render that. For instance:

```
while not stop:
        original_txt = 'Click ENTER to continue...'
        text_to_be_displayed = original_txt[1]
        gameDisplay.blit(Map, (0,0))

        StoryText = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",25)

        StoryFont = StoryText.render(text_to_be_displayed,5,(red))
        gameDisplay.blit(StoryFont,(50,500))
```

Hope this helped.